# Is it possible to have thousands of different shop linked to the same loyalty card in wallet on iOS or Android equivalent?

Tags: android, ios, android-pay, applepay, wallet

I am planning to make a loyalty card program for thousands of shops.

When a user pays its bill with Apple/Android pay, I want that the loyalty card is automatically credited with f(billAmount).
I know it is possible to do so with automatic selection option in an iOS loyalty card. 
But does it work when you have more than one shop link to this card? Could it works with thousands of different shops linked to the same card?

(I am not an iOS/Android native programmer so I am not used to the wallet specs so I don't need implementation details.)

Comment: Yes, it is theoretically possible, but practically impossible because of the need for al of the store's POS systems to be linked into your program.  In reality most POS systems are closed and difficult to integrate, many lack realtime internet capability (batch updates), and if you wanted to use the NFC capabilities of Apple Wallet and Android Smart Tap, the terminal firmware would require firmware modifications which would then require certification before it could be used to process transactions.  All of these factors together make what you suggest an impractical impossibility.

Comment: Make sens. The firmware modification is, as always, the main obstacle. I guess Engenico Thelium Tetra or equivalent will remove this difficulty but the deployment is not ready until years.